# How to perform indirect references into a variant column?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, variant, indirection

I'm determining the structure/query I would need to handle indirect references into a variant column (i.e. I want to extract different fields for different rows based on the definitions of another table).

Example:
I have variant data that represents different items each of which have completely different sets of properties based on a category they belong to.
While these properties are named differently depending on the category, there are some common purposes that can be shared/identified.

So I have a table (properties) that defines the property name for each purpose/category combination

Properties

```
| Category | Purpose | Property_Name | Property_Data_Type |
|----------|---------|---------------|--------------------|
|    car   |   name  |  model        |    string          |
|    car   |  brand  |  make         |    string          |
|    car   |  price  |  invoice      |    number          |
|  phone   |   name  |  product      |    string          |
|  phone   |  brand  |  manufacturer |    string          |
|  phone   |  price  |  msrp         |    number          |
|----------|---------|---------------|--------------------|
```

and I have a table (items) that contains the information for each item in a variant field

Items

```
| Item_Id | Category | Properties                                                       |   
|---------|----------|------------------------------------------------------------------|
|     1   |   car    | {"make":"ford", "model":"focus", "invoice":18999}                |
|     2   |   car    | {"make":"audi", "model":"a5", "invoice":36487}                   |
|     3   | phone    | {"manufacturer":"apple", "product":"iphone 10", "msrp":679}      |
|     4   | phone    | {"manufacturer":"samsung", "product":"galaxy s20",  "msrp":1029} |
|---------|----------|------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

What I want to be able to do is to get a query (or a process to populate another table) that would extract the values from the json data based on the property purpose that is defined.
So I would have a query that could give the following results

```
| Item_Id | Category | Name       | Brand   | Price |
|---------|----------|------------|---------|-------|
|    1    |  car     | focus      | ford    | 18999 |
|    2    |  car     | a5         | audi    | 36487 |
|    3    |  phone   | iphone 10  | apple   |   679 |
|    4    |  phone   | galaxy s20 | samsung |  1029 |
|---------|----------|------------|---------|-------|
```

Comment: Have you looked into stored procedures with Snowflake? You won't be able to do this with SQL but stored procs you probably could

Comment: I've done something similar in python, so I suspect that Javascript SP's would work.  The challenge would be if your json field has a hierarchy to it.  That would get complicated pretty quickly, but also doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was bored so I wrote this. It's a stored procedure that will create or replace a view called ITEM_VIEW according to your description above. Note that there's a minor discrepancy in your data. The property for phone in the JSON is "model", but in the PROPERTIES table it's "manufacturer".

Any time you change the PROPERTIES table, you'll need to run the stored procedure to rebuild the view. I put the SQL statement and clauses into templates so you can modify as required.

As you can see in the code, the stored procedure is expecting a table named PROPERTIES and a table named ITEMS. If your actual table names are different, you can change them in the code and/or SQL templates where you find them.

```
create or replace procedure CREATE_ITEM_VIEW()
returns string
language javascript
as
$$

var nameClause = "";
var brandClause = "";
var priceClause = "";
var category, purpose, dataType, property;

var rs = GetResultSet("select * from PROPERTIES");

while (rs.next()){

    category = rs.getColumnValue("CATEGORY");
    purpose  = rs.getColumnValue("PURPOSE");
    property = rs.getColumnValue("PROPERTY_NAME");
    dataType = rs.getColumnValue("PROPERTY_DATA_TYPE");

    if (purpose == 'name'){
        nameClause += GetColumn(category, property, dataType) + "\n";
    }
    if (purpose == 'brand'){
        brandClause += GetColumn(category, property, dataType) + "\n";
    }
    if (purpose == 'price'){
        priceClause += GetColumn(category, property, dataType) + "\n";
    }
}

var viewSQL = GetViewSQL(nameClause, brandClause, priceClause);

return ExecuteSingleValueQuery("status", viewSQL);

// ----------------------End of Main Function ---------------------------------------

function GetColumn(category, name, dataType){
    var sql = "when '@~CATEGORY~@'    then PROPERTIES:@~NAME~@::@~NAME_DATA_TYPE~@";
    sql = sql.replace(/@~CATEGORY~@/g,       category);
    sql = sql.replace(/@~NAME~@/g,           name);
    sql = sql.replace(/@~NAME_DATA_TYPE~@/g, dataType);
    return sql;
}

function GetViewSQL(nameClause, brandClause, priceClause){

var sql = `
create or replace view ITEM_VIEW as
select  ITEM_ID,
        CATEGORY, 
        case CATEGORY

${nameClause}
        end as "NAME",
        case CATEGORY

${brandClause}
        end as BRAND,
        case CATEGORY

${priceClause}
        end as PRICE
from ITEMS;
`;
return sql;
}

function GetResultSet(sql){
    cmd1 = {sqlText: sql};
    stmt = snowflake.createStatement(cmd1);
    var rs;
    rs = stmt.execute();
    return rs;
}

function ExecuteSingleValueQuery(columnName, queryString) {
    var out;
    cmd1 = {sqlText: queryString};
    stmt = snowflake.createStatement(cmd1);
    var rs;

    rs = stmt.execute();
    rs.next();
    return rs.getColumnValue(columnName);
    return out;
}

$$;
```

Once you create the stored procedure, run it like this and it will create your view:

```
call create_item_view();

select * from ITEM_VIEW;
```

Comment: I will take a look at this.  I have edited the original post to be consistent now.  I don't believe it was the manufacturer/model that was inconsistent - but the name/model that was labelled incorrectly.  Thank you.

Comment: Makes sense... If you have any problems getting it to work, let me know.

Comment: Ok - this definitely did work for me.  I had one question though - and that is if there is a particular reason you made three different functions for the Get___Column logic?  It seemed to me that you could generalize this and just use a single function for this behavior.

Comment: You make a good point. While working on it, I refactored some code and didn't realize the Get___Column stuff was all the same. I updated the example and switched to standard JavaScript replacement tokens ${variableName} where they work. Sometimes they don't seem to work when surrounded by special characters, so I left the replacement tokens there.